# window.location picks IP address and not the domain name

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, subdomain, ip-address, google-picker

I've my ruby on rails website registered as a subdomain under godaddy.com

It works fine. But when I try to get the window.location.host, It returns the IP address of my server and not the domain name.

Because of this I'm getting the following error with my google picker js api:

```
    Incorrect origin value. Please set it to - (window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host) of the top-most page
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: If you see actual sub-domain in address bar but different host in location.host then some script has overridden it. But it is hard to over-ride window.locaion. Please check what is there in window.location? http://jsbin.com/welosote/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yes.. The actual subdomain name is displayed in the address bar, but in window.location I get the IP address of that subdomain itself.

Comment: Is that code/window in iframe?

Comment: Yes. I've not used any iFrame, But on browser it's getting enclosed by an iFrame with src = 'IP address'

Comment: That's the issue then. You can't do anything expect using that IP address as your domain name. (BTW might want to talk with GoDaddy folks if there is work around).

Comment: But I can't use the IP address with Google Picker API. Thats the main issue. Is there any way to remove this iframe, by changing any settings with godaddy (in case you have any idea about it) ?

Comment: Don't know. You are using GoDaddy for hosting as well I assume. If not everything is under your control and it seems odd that GoDaddy would impelment hosting that way.

Comment: Yeah.. I've mentioned in my question that my site is under godaddy only. But thanks for all your help @amitamb

Comment: thanks @amitamb ... the issue was with godaddy hosting.. it was hosted with IP forward and masking.. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the domain might be set in domain forwarding mode. The domain needs to actually point to the IP which is different than domain forwarding.