# How to get exact origin domain address in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am facing problem on getting origin domain address.
I tried document.location, $location but no solution. It returns ip address instead of actual domain address.

Finally i tried **window.location.ancestorOrigins**. it works in chrome and safari but does not for firefox and IE. it's showing undefined.
The ip address mapping is done in godaddy(ip address forwarding).
Can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `window.location.hostname` ?

Comment: No,i tried it returns ipaddress not actual domain address @Adriani6

Comment: It should show the domain name, May I know where did you host your code ?

Comment: And what do you see in browser URL, domain name or IP address ?

Answer (score 7):

You can see by accessing a console (F12) and entering `location` that this variable provides some interesting properties:

```
assign: ƒ() hash: ""
host: "stackoverflow.com"
hostname: "stackoverflow.com"
href: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274883/how-to-get-exact-origin-domain-address-in-javascript"
origin: "https://stackoverflow.com"
pathname: "/questions/52274883/how-to-get-exact-origin-domain-address-in-javascript"
port: ""
protocol: "https:"
```

If I understand right your question, you may want to access `window.location.origin`.

Comment: No its not working.it brings ip address.But if i use window.location.ancestorOrigins then it is working but not in firefox and IE.it shows undefined

Comment: Then you can't do anything by the client side, you probably need to follow instructions from this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43263849/8764888

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer does not have access to window.location.origin, which is a bummer because it is a pretty handy variable to have, but we can make it work with a fairly straight forward check because we access .origin;

```
if (!window.location.origin) {
  window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
}
```

This should now have .origin set to what you would expect.

Comment: I tried window.location.hostname .it returns ip address not domain address.

Comment: Can i know what you enter in browser ip address or domain?

Comment: window.location.ancestorOrigins; is only concerns parent frame Please see report in which browser it is work https://huge-dom.vanilla-cms.org/window.location.ancestorOrigins